# How does Nick's idea about letter writing on envelopes works exactly?

Tags: plot-explanation, push

In *Push (2009)*, *Nick* explains idea about writting letters on envelopes to each of the group, telling them only when they should be opened to receive instructions. He will then go to the *Wiper* who cleared *Kira*'s memory and have the memory of having written the letters erased.

I didn't understand the Nick's idea here.

How does Nick's idea about letter writing on envelopes work exactly?

Answer (score 1):

When the instructions were written on envelopes, this means at the very least, their plan is safe: it won't be read from their minds because it's *not* in there, erased by the Wiper. If they knew exactly all the details of the plan and one of them somehow gets abducted, then the plan fails, because it can be read from their minds.

Source: I saw the movie a couple of times already to comprehend some things :)

Comment: Hello @cpe.Prince you just pasted question with placing words differently. It didn't actually answer the question. I will wait for better answer to it.